# After entering password in keyring box the desktop freezes

Tags: gnome, 10.04, keyrings

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm afraid I've done something really stupid.

After booting, When prompted to enter a password to unlock my login keyring, I tried to enter my password, but it won't let me.

I can move my cursor but everything else is frozen.

I tried to access the terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, I entered my login and password from there and it worked, I just don't know what to do afterwards.

Don't know what other information I can provide other than the fact that I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 8):

Switch to X (the graphical interface that is frozen) usually by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and then type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> .

This will kill X and it will restart. This is kind of a "nasty" solution but without additional details and debugging is the best I can offer.

-- or --

logged in on a virtual console (or remotely) type `sudo service gdm restart`

Comment: YW, glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>?

Seems silly but I used to have something like this happen to me. Gnome would load up and a keyring unlock prompt would show. If I entered within a minute, fine. If I took too long the system would focus on something else (that I couldn't see) and the mouse or keyboard wouldn't let me move back to unlock it.

One day I mashed the keyboard in frustration, hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> by accident and the keyring box reloaded, allowing me to type its password.

I've since found that the reason the login pops up is because of `network-manager`. I've changed all my connections so that "Available to all users" is checked and now I don't get any annoying popups. I'm told removing the password from the keyring is another solution but it's less secure.